# Physics Dropping Ball Blur

Tags: physics, path, blur

Friends,

Maybe some of you have seen on a golf telecast where the putter hits the ball and all the "frames" of the ball rolling toward the hole suddenly become one, long "blur". I hope you get my drift. I'm doing something in Physics where I drop a ball at an angle and see how it bounces against the wall. Sure would be great if I could see the "path" in real time. Got the whole "world" of the 2 walls, ball, and floor set up, just need that path blur (if that's possible). Thanks so much, everyone!  Larry

Comment: hello maybe show a picture of the effect?

Comment: I assume you are talking about path tracing and object ghosting. Please edit your question and include an example image also clarify the final goal. Do you want to see the ball path or you want to include it in your render? A heads up - currently Blender does not include such overlays except the Motion Path overlay which works with keyframed objects. However there may be third party tracer add-ons that could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

i think animation nodes (a great free add-on) can help you in that situation a lot:

Basically you just bake your rigid body animation.

After you baked it, just use this node setup:

[image]

So the Sphere has the baked keyframes, which are "in Blender language" fcurves. Each fcurve represents one value. So in my case, i baked location and rotation, the first fcurve (index = 0) has got the x values, index = 1 the y-values, and index = 2 has got the z values. Then i just created a very simple loop over all frames (117 in my case) which evaluate the fcurves (the nodes spits out the value, so here xyz, and combine these values to a vector and combine the vectors via the loop to a vector list. Then i can create a spline out of this list. Give that spline some bevel + shader and i think you can get what you want, maybe something like this:

[image]

Comment: Chris,  Thanks so much for your answer! That's EXACTLY what I was looking for...... unfortunately for me, who barely know the basics of Blender,  it's way over my head (what you were trying to explain). Will keep looking at it, though.  Larry